# Why are these 8 byte-writes not optimized into a MOV?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, x86, micro-optimization

My colleague and myself are unsuccessful in explaining why GCC, ICC and Clang do not optimize this function

```
void f(std::uint64_t a, void * p) {
    std::uint8_t *x = reinterpret_cast<std::uint8_t *>(p);
    x[7] = a >> 56;
    x[6] = a >> 48;
    x[5] = a >> 40;
    x[4] = a >> 32;
    x[3] = a >> 24;
    x[2] = a >> 16;
    x[1] = a >> 8;
    x[0] = a;
}
```

Into this

```
mov     QWORD PTR [rsi], rdi
```

If we formulate `f` in terms of `memcpy`, it emits just that `mov`. Why [does it not happen](https://godbolt.org/g/kEVCsZ) if we do the seemingly trivial sequence of byte writes?

Comment: optimizers work in mysterious ways... have you tried reversing the order (starting from 0 to 7) ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes, did not help

Comment: what about a loop then?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre we tried. and enabled -ftree-vectorize and other weird things. And we observed it unrolled the loop. But it didn't turn it into a MOV.

Comment: maybe compiler doesn't want to do that because of unknown memory alignment? have you tried telling the compiler about the alignment? (8-bytes alignment then)

Comment: I'm never surprised by what isn't optimized; I'm constantly surprised by what *is*.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre my colleague has a corresponding read function which does the exact reverse (using bitwise-OR in a single `return` statement). And for that it *does* use MOV.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre telling about alignment doesn't seem to help either: https://godbolt.org/g/MxtezH

Comment: I also tried `(*(std::uint64_t*)x) = a;` no QWORD issued.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre if I say `*(std::uint64_t*)x = a;`, it emits a QWORD MOV for me.

Comment: @MarkRansom we would welcome experts insights into this. Is it not a pattern common enough to waste an optimizer pass for? Do reordering CPUs already detect this and treat it specially? Any other reason?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb my compiler is probably 32-bit only.

Comment: I wish I had expert insights in this area. Unfortunately I don't which is why I get surprised.

Comment: CPUs don't handle this specially.  This is just a missed optimization in gcc/clang/ICC/MSVC, and will run slowly (one store per clock, and a lot more front-end instructions / uops to decode and issue into the out-of-order core).  IDK why gcc doesn't find it.  gcc7/8 does coalesce stores of compile-time constants.  See https://godbolt.org/g/pNLB3M for example.  (I also tried a simpler version of your function with two 16-bit halves of a 32-bit integer, and tried C instead of C++.  No luck, I didn't get compilers to ever coalesce stores of shift results of a variable.)

Comment: It's unfortunate that patterns like this are handled so badly, because it's useful for endian-agnostic code.  https://commandcenter.blogspot.ca/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html.  Oh actually, loads do coalesce https://godbolt.org/g/TudyWS (except with `clang -mavx2` which goes berserk.)  But not with ICC/MSVC, only clang and (recent) gcc.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think GCC has supported coalescing endian-agnostic code in the past, but it has either bit-rotted or been removed because alignment or other issues. It's how I've handled endian issues for over twenty years now and I vaguely remember GCC optimizing it down to simple MOV instructions in the past.

Comment: Not sure if relevant but multiple moves have different multi-thread semantics than a single, atomic move operation. They are not equivalent in a multi-threaded context. That could be a blocker for the given optimization.

Comment: @SedatKapanoglu: no they don't, not if all of the stores happen unconditionally in the C or C++ source.  Data races (on non-`atomic` objects) are UB, so the compiler is free to do the writes however it wants.  The OP is using `-std=c++17`, so unlike C++03 or something, the language *has* a memory model which defines this rule.

Comment: @PeterCordes i didn’t know they were regarded UB. Thanks!

Comment: It would be doable but not trivial. However, gcc already has a bswap recognition pass, which might only require a tweak to handle this case (maybe turning (unsigned char)(x >> 16) into a BIT_FIELD_REF). People who care already have 2 compile-time paths, one with the identity and one calling intrinsics like _bswap64.

Comment: By the way, if you want something that is recognized by compilers, you should read bytes from memory and reconstruct an integer using shift and or, that's easier than the reverse.

Comment: Since there is activity on the topic in gcc right now, it wouldn't hurt to post the testcase on gcc's bugzilla.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I would welcome if you posted it. I don't have much time on my hands right now

Comment: It is optimized now with gcc trunk!

Comment: @MarcGlisse amazing, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I'm not an expert, but gcc only gained the ability to merge adjacent stores for immediate constants in gcc 7:

- *Closed* bug for immediate constants: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23684
- *Open* bug for assignment of small structs:https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78821
- Store-merging pass code: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/gimple-ssa-store-merging.c

If I had to guess, by the second bug, it might not be too long a wait.

Comment: Ah, yes I'd noticed that gcc7 finally re-introduced store merging (after gcc3 or gcc4 regressed from gcc2.95 *many* years ago), but hadn't realized it was only for compile-time constants.  I was surprised that none of clang, icc, or MSVC did the merging, though.  clang does merge in struct-member copy case https://godbolt.org/g/GDvEV8 (gcc bug 78821), but gcc current still doesn't, nor do ICC nor MSVC.

Comment: Store merging just got improved (https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2017-11/msg00258.html) and is not limited to constants anymore, though it still doesn't handle the OP's code.